# How to cast both sides of Either?

Tags: flutter, dart, dartz

I am trying to have `Either<Failure, Concrete>` where `Concrete` extends `Abstract` class, but I cannot get it to work. If I try to cast the left side I get the error:

```
type 'Right<Failure, Concrete>' is not a subtype of type 'Either<Failure, Abstract>' in type cast
```

if I try for the right side I get:

```
type 'Left<Object, Concrete>' is not a subtype of type 'Either<Failure, Concrete>' in type cast
```

And `bimap` does not seems to solve it. Is there an easy way to do it? tks

Comment: Please provide minimal but complete code that can reproduce the problem you're trying to describe.

Comment: in fpdart, you can do that with Either.safeCast, just rolled out yesterday.  And I strongly recommend you switch from dartz to fpdart.